# fancybox thumb not working

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, thumbnails, fancybox-2

I have in my webpage **Fancybox 2** thumbnails.

One thumb is working, but the second isn't. Instead, it opens that second thumb in the browser tab.

How can I fix this so the second thumb works correctly in Fancybox?

**HTML:**

```html
<script>
      $('.slideshow-thumbs2').fancybox({
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        closeBtn: false,
        arrows: false,
        nextClick: true,
        helpers: {
          thumbs: {
            width: 50,
            height: 50
          }
        }
      });
</script>

<a class="slideshow-thumbs2" rel="slideshow-thumbs2" href="/SSJ100/Prev1.jpg" title="Superjet 100">
  <img src="/SSJ100/Prev1.jpg" width="220px" height="200px" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 1px black; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; " alt="" class="active"/>
</a>

<a class="slideshow-thumbs2" rel="slideshow-thumbs2" href="/SSJ100/Prev2.jpg" title="Superjet 100">
  <img src="/SSJ100/Prev2.jpg" width="220px" height="200px" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 1px black; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; " alt=""/>
</a>

<a class="slideshow-thumbs2" rel="slideshow-thumbs2" href="/SSJ100/Prev3.jpg" title="Superjet 100">
  <img src="/SSJ100/Prev3.jpg" width="220px" height="200px" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 1px black; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; " alt=""/>
</a>

<a class="slideshow-thumbs2" rel="slideshow-thumbs2" href="/SSJ100/Prev4.jpg" title="Superjet 100">
  <img src="/SSJ100/Prev4.jpg" width="220px" height="200px" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 1px black; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; " alt=""/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

[**jsFiddle DEMO: Fancybox v2.1.3 and Thumbnail Helper**](http://jsfiddle.net/xL7ez/)

Your pasted code shows that the very first Fancybox item has `class="active"` which may affect the other thumbs from not working.

However, there isn't enough information to determine why it only works for 1 thumb and not the other if that isn't the problem.

Make sure you've loaded at least **jQuery v1.6.4** and are using **4 Fancybox2 files**.

Two files are for Fancybox, ***and the remaining two files*** are for the **Thumbnail Helper** feature as shown in your `.fancybox()` function. You can find those helper files are in the **helper folder** from the downloaded **Fancybox 2** installation files you have.

The **4 mini-thumbnails** that are shown inside Fancybox 2 screenshot below is by using the **Thumbnail Helper** files of `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css` and `jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap your code inside the `ready()` method like :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slideshow-thumbs2').fancybox({
        prevEffect: 'none',
        nextEffect: 'none',
        closeBtn: false,
        arrows: false,
        nextClick: true,
        helpers: {
          thumbs: {
            width: 50,
            height: 50
          }
        }
      });
 });
</script>
```